# C - Exceção lançada ao scanf_s ler string

Tags: c

Estou realizando uma série de atividades da minha faculdade que devem ser feitas utilizando C, estou tento dificuldades pois estou acostumado a usar apenas C++, primeiro estava utilizando scanf mas o visual studio não compilava indicando erros de segurança, então migrei para scanf_s, compilou, porém ao ler uma string recebo o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eis o código:

```
struct Conta {
    char *nome;
    int numeroConta;
    int kwConsumidos;
};

struct Conta conta;

printf("Insira o nome: \n");
scanf_s("%s", &conta.nome);
```

Comment: Um conselho. No visual studio, quando programar em C, prefira usar o compilador clang(pode ser baixado pelo visual installer) do que o MVSC (o compilador natural do visual studio) porque o visual studio, para C, tem um sério problema de compatibilidade com as regras da ISO standard. Essas funções de módulo <stdio.h> terminadas em _s não são reconhecidas por outros compiladores, então, o código não é portável, além disso, o MVSC não tem suporte para _Generic, faz confusão com noreturn, não tem VLA..., enfim, é bastante problemático programar C com ele.

Comment: @v.Santos eu gosto de usar llvm em meus projetos, porém quem vai corrigir a atividade não vai querer fazer isso

Answer (score 1):

Peça ao professor que te explique novamente sobre ponteiros.

O membro 'nome' da estrutura 'conta' é um ponteiro, ele precisa estar alocado, para ter espaço que receba a string inserida.

Além disso, por conta do &, você está passando um ponteiro para o ponteiro, do tipo char**, mas scanf/scanf_s pede o tipo char* para a máscara %s.

Comment: mas como vou alocar memoria para o ponteiro se eu nao sei o tamanho que o usuario vai inserir?

Comment: Pois é, esta é uma limitação fundamental de scanf() & cia. Você vai ter de definir um tamanho máximo e alocar. A função scanf_s() permite passar um terceiro parâmetro com este tamanho, aí pelo menos o programa não vai explodir se o input ultrapassá-lo.

Comment: Passando o tamanho para a função fez funcionar

Comment: É, é melhor especificar, mas se não alocar espaço para Conta.nome e continuar enviando char** em vez de char*, está escrevendo a string em algum lugar misterioso, parou de quebrar por sorte.

Comment: Eu mudei de ponteiro pra array e passei o tamanho do array com parametro